Find the json field dynamically when user send the field path?
I'm currently working on a spring boot application where I have find a way to meet the following requirement

When user send a path to a field of a json I have to find that that field on the json and return that to the user
When user send a path to a field of a json with data to update the json I have to update the json and store it in the db

Sample of json I'm getting
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "a": "New York Bulls"
                    },
                    {
                        "b": "Los Angeles Kings"
                    },
                    {
                        "c": "Golden State Warriros"
                    },
                    {
                        "d": "Huston Rocket"
                    }
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "a": "10"
                    },
                    {
                        "b": "11"
                    },
                    {
                        "c": "12"
                    },
                    {
                        "d": "13"
                    }
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}

sample user request for requirement 1

quiz/sport/q1/option/a = "New York Bulls"
quiz/maths/q1/option/a = "10"
depending on the json this can change
response respectively should be -

 a: "New York Bulls"

 a: "10" 


sample user requests for requirement 2

quiz/sport/q1/option/a = "New York Bulls"
data to change - "Washinton Bulls"
this should update the json as

 a: "Washinton Bulls" 


There can multiple different type of json and therefore many different type of requests requesting data of those jsons
technologies I'm Using
java / Spring Boot / PostgreSql - string column to store json
Is there any better way to do this using the technologies I mentioned ?
My Current Approaches
I can't use path variables or query parameters because depending on the json users requests path changes.
So I'm using a post request to get the users request (getting the path of the json as a string)
Convert the string json (Which is stored in the db) to a json node (JSONNode Class) and find the required field

Your "options" are invalid above. Arrays cannot be keyed.

yeah if it is arrary object I have to iterate and find the matching key and get that objecy

I mean that your JSON that your provided is INVALID. Please update the question to reflect valid JSON data. You can lint it with JSONLint before you update your post with the correct JSON.

Take a look at JsonPath. Given a JSON, it allows you to get and set values using a convenient dot notation.
For example, this is how you can get a value
$.quiz.sport.q1.option.a

and this is how you can set a value
JsonPath.parse(json).set("$['quiz']['sport']['q1']['option']['a']", "Washinton Bulls").jsonString();

